# How do I write an .htaccess rewrite rule to convert query strings into segmented URIs?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, query-string

Is there a way to put a rewrite rule in htaccess that will convert query strings to segmented URIs? For eg.

```
http://domain.com/controller/method/?a=1&b=2&c=3
```

should get rewritten as

```
http://domain.com/controller/method/a/1/b/2/c/3
```

All there is to do is remove the ? and replace the &s and the =s with a /, but I'm not quite sure how all that figures into .htaccess...

Not that it'd matter, but I'm using PHP and CodeIgniter on Apache.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you put that logic inside your CodeIgniter controller instead of doing it in .htaccess ?

Check [CodeIgniter's User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html) for handling Query Strings and URLs.

Comment: I'm having trouble with CodeIgniter receiving the query strings from the URL. It works fine on the local server, but on the live server, the moment I put anything after a `?` at the end simply makes CI throw up a 404. That's why I want to rewrite the query string into a segmented URI so CI doesn't throw it's hands up.

Comment: @aalaap you can enable query strings in CI by setting $config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE; check this: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in the .htaccess you need to have mod_rewrite.

The rule is not too difficult. I give you a minimal example, and you need to tune the regex up to fix your need.

```
RewiteRule ^/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)$ /method/?$1=$2
```

Comment: I need to do the exact opposite of what you're doing with this rule!

Answer (score 0):

This is what you could do:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?]*\?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)&([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)&?(.*)
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}/%1/%2/%3/%4?%5 [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?]*\?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)&?(.*)
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?/%1/%2?%3 [L]
```

Comment: Wouldn't there be a way to rewrite the URLs without a redirect? I mean, that's what `mod_rewrite` is for, right! What would happen if I was to drop the `R=301` from the rules you put down?